# gcc46 and no c compiler found on Amazon EC2

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, yum, gcc, gearman

I've been trying to install Gearman on my EC2 instance, but when I try to ./configure gearmand, I get this:

```
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking target system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for gcc... no
checking for cc... no
checking for cl.exe... no
configure: error: in `/home/ec2-user/gearmand-1.1.3':
configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH
See `config.log' for more details
```

Now, the strange thing is that GCC is most definitely installed.

```
which gcc46
```

returns

```
/usr/bin/gcc46
```

However, when I try to run the command "gcc", it's not found...

I've tried to erase/intall/reinstall gcc and gcc-c++ via yum, but that doesn't seem to be helping.

Any advice? Thanks in advance.

Comment: And which Linux distribution are you using?

Comment: It's an Amazon Linux AMI instance. I believe it's CentOS? Not sue, though.

Comment: "Amazon Linux" only uses yum and RPM. It is not CentOS nor based on it. I don't recommend using it.

Comment: Well, I'm only using it as a development sandbox. Any idea on how to fix the problem in the original post?

Comment: There is a good chance that configure looks for `which gcc` (i.e. without a version number). In many cases (including Amazon Linux) gcc is symlinked to a versioned file. For instance one of my servers (Amazon Linux 2012.09) has `/usr/bin/gcc` --> `/etc/alternatives/gcc` --> `/usr/bin/gcc44`. The amzn repository has a package group called 'Development tools' which should provide everything needed to compile common software (although I dislike it on a production server). Check/create the symlinks (or try using `alternatives`) as some gcc versions don't set them automatically.

Comment: Probably rather outdated, but Amazon Linux is fully compatible with EPEL (at least the recent versions are - they come with it setup (but not enabled) by default) and EPEL provides gearmand (v0.14) in its repository.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install dependencies listed in [.travis.yml](https://github.com/gearman/gearmand/blob/master/.travis.yml#L29-L39).